# Remember multiple divs toggleClass with jQuery Cookie

Tags: jquery, html, css, cookies

I have two `div`s (`staticclose` and `sads`). The first one is visible and the other one is hidden. When I close the first `div`, the second one becomes visible and when I click the second `div`, the first one becomes visible. How can I use [jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to remember the state of the `div`s?

```
$('.staticclose').click(function(){ 
  $('.static-ad').toggleClass('hide');
  $('.sads').toggleClass('hide');
});

$('.sads').click(function(){ 
  $('.static-ad').toggleClass('hide');
  $('.sads').toggleClass('hide'); 
});
```

Comment: i have not heard of jquery cookie. but if you want to remember state, use html attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `jQuery.cookie` as you ask in your question, you could do something like:

```
$('.staticclose').click(function(){ 
  $('.static-ad').toggleClass('hide');
  $('.sads').toggleClass('hide');
  $.cookie("last_state", "0", {path: "/"});
});

$('.sads').click(function(){ 
  $('.static-ad').toggleClass('hide');
  $('.sads').toggleClass('hide'); 
  $.cookie("last_state", "1", {path: "/"});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($.cookie("last_state") === "1") {
    //Do whatever you want
  } else {
    //Do whatever you want
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies or HTML5 Storage. I prefer the second option.

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/

Simple example with amplify.

First store the object.

```
amplify.store( "yourObject", { foo: "bar" } );
```

Then retrieve it.

```
var retrievedValue = amplify.store( "yourObject" );
```

Simple example with jquery cookies.

Set:

```
$.cookie('staticclose', 'visible');
$.cookie('sads', 'invisible');
```

Get:

```
$.cookie('staticclose'); // "visible"
$.cookie('sads'); // "invisible"
```

Anyhow, you can use data attributes to accomplish this. 
But if your idea is remember the state after reloading the page, ok, go for the cookies idea.

Example with data attributes:

```
$("#div1").data("currentState", "visible");
$("#div2").data("currentState", "invisible");
```

To retrieve the data:

```
var div1 = $("#div1").data("currentState"); // It will be "visible"
var div2 = $("#div2").data("currentState"); // It will be "invisible"
```